# Batch fixing corrupted JPG files?

Tags: jpeg

Ugh.  So I went on a vacation in Indonesia and the photographer just sent (after 6 weeks) a USB with about 300 photos, each 6.5 or so MB large...and only FOUR open up into actual JPGs.  EVERY OTHER IMAGE doesn't display a thumbnail and won't open -- I've tried renaming the files as JPGs, tried guessing if it's a png or gif and renaming them that way, tried dragging into Chrome (apparently a robust file viewer).

When I open with Image Viewer (I'm on Lubuntu 18.04LTS) I get an error:

"Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xff"

And when I use "file" I get this:

"ISO-8859 text, with very long lines and no line terminators"

Sooooo...that's why these aren't opening up.  Unfortunately I can't reconnect with the driver so my ONLY hope in getting these vacation pics is to somehow bulk fix them.  Even if it's painful.  I don't have much hope but if anyone knows what's happened I would love to know if there's anything I can try.  I am thinking doing some kind of hex editor might remove the initial tag and make it a JPG again???  The fact that they are the right size seems to make me think maybe it's just a small thing that has gotten borked here and maybe I could fix it manually.

As mentioned above, running Lubuntu 18.04LTS.  Any help or thoughts would be great.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the files with a Hex editor program, and also looking at some known-valid .jpg files with the same editor, and seeing if what is different between the "good" and the "bad" files (especially the first few hundred bytes of the files, which is where the headers are).  That might give you a better sense of what the problem is, and whether it's reparable.

Comment: Thank you!  I will try that.

Comment: You got anything? I have the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing worked.  I had to accept that the data was just gone.  A huge loss, but the price we pay for going digital.